# How to find $\dim( \operatorname{span}(M)+ \operatorname{span}(N))$ and $\dim(\operatorname{span}(M\cap N))$?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

$M=\{(1,2,1),(3,1,5),(3,-4,7)\}$, $N=\{(1,0,-1),(1,2,1)\}$

Let $A=  \operatorname{span}(M)$ and $B= \operatorname{span}(N)$

I want to know how to find $\;(a)\;\dim(A+B)$ and $(b)\;\dim(A\cap B)$

\begin{bmatrix}
   1  & 3 & 3  \\
    2  & 1  & -4  \\
    1 & 5 & 7  
\end{bmatrix}$ \sim$
\begin{bmatrix}
   1  & 3 & 3  \\
    0  & 1  & 2  \\
    0 & 0 & 0  
\end{bmatrix}
Since, only the first two vectors are linearly independent, we have $\dim(A)=2$

Clearly, $\dim(B)=2$ since it is a linearly independent set(They are not multiple of each other).

I want to make use of:

$\dim(A+B)= \dim(A)+\dim(B)-\dim(A\cap B)$

So how do I find either of $\dim(A+B)$ or $\dim(A\cap B)$ to get the other ?

Does making a single matrix with the vectors in $M$ and $N$ and calculating its rank help?

\begin{bmatrix}
   1  & 3 & 3 & 1 &1\\
    2  & 1  & -4&0 &2 \\
    1 & 5 & 7  &-1&1
\end{bmatrix}
$\sim$
\begin{bmatrix}
   1  & 3 & 3 & 1 &1\\
    0  & -5  & -10&-2 &0 \\
    0 & 0 & 0  &14&0
\end{bmatrix}
So this gives a rank of 3

Comment: @DietrichBurde I row reduced to find that only first and second vectors are linearly independent. So doesn't that mean its dimension is 2?

Comment: Yes, it does. But where is this written? "So, $\dim(A)=2$" is a very poor proof.

Comment: I have written the matrices in my post

Comment: You have written the matrices, yes, but no word about why the rank is not full.

Comment: To find $dim(A+B)$ you can put the generating vectors of $A$ and $B$ in the columns of a matrix and do the same thing as before.

Comment: ok let me add it, but can you help me with dimension of $A+B$ and $A\cap B$

Comment: Yes, I wanted to help you anyway. Therefore you first have to argue for $\dim (A)$ and **then** do the same for $\dim(A+B)$. I was not sure, that you know how to do this.

Comment: Another way to solve this is to notice that $(1,2,1)$ is in both $A$ and $B$, so $dim(A\cap B)\geq 1$. We also have $2=dim(A)\geq dim(A+B)$. You thus see that $dim(A+B)=2$ if and only if $(1,0,-1)\in A$. When the dimension is not 2, due to the above inequality $dim(A+B)=1$.

Comment: "Dimension" applies to vector spaces. $M+N$ and $M\cap N$ are not vector spaces, so they don't have dimensions, and the question makes no sense.

Comment: @Kolja I put all the vectors in a single matrix and the rank of this matrix is 3? what does this mean?

Comment: @GerryMyerson you're right. that was a typing error from my side

Comment: I made a mistake in a previous comment. If you found that all the vectors create a matrix of rank 3 that means that $dim(A+B)=3$.

Comment: Previously I was meaning to write $2\leq dim(A+B) \leq 3$ with $dim(A+B)=2$ if and only if $(1,0,-1)\in A$.

Comment: Yes, augmenting the matrix helps. Computing the null space of the matrix, as you show that the rank of the matrix is 3, hence the dimension of its null space is 2. Two solution we can obtain is $(1,0,0,0,−1),(−3,2,−1,0,0)$
. Since one of the vector has all nonzero entries on the first three row, and no vector with all nonzero entries on the last two row, hence the dimension of their intersection is $=2-1=1$.